# Best way to auto-refresh a web-page (conditional)

Tags: python, jquery, ajax

I am working on a wesbsite and would like to know how to auto-refresh the webpage?
I am not looking for meta tag refresh or timer based refresh. I am looking for conditional refresh.

One use-case would be as below:
User1 and User2 are friends (like facebook)
User1 updates his name on the website. User2's home page should get refreshed as soon there is a state change in User1's profile.

I am thinking I could have a ajax request that hits my API server, API server will spawn a new thread that will keep checking if there is any change in user1's profile, if yes return true else false.

If it returns True, I will reload the page in the success of Ajax call.

However, I am not sure if this is the best way of doing this. Could someone please guide me?

Comment: I think you should look at websockets, crossbar.io and autobahn are well documented

Comment: hi @SedyVlk could you please explain you comment little bit more? I am already using WSGI server to host my API servers.

Comment: Well look at what WebSockets do, crossbar.io implements WebSocket router and autobahn is a python client library. You can write a bit of javascript on your side and fetch only bit of info that you need. In your example, you would not actually even refresh entire page but only the bit that are needed. So if user1 changes his name on the web user2( and all other friends of user1) would get the the new name. It may require you rewrite your web app a little ( hopefully incrementaly), just look at few examples and you will see if this is for you or not